# Android: What is the order of all item in a layout?

Tags: android

I notice that there is a method `getChildAt()` which can get the certain item in a layout. However, I cannot find where does the order define. Please help.

Comment: They are numbered based on their hierarchy

Comment: child order is order inserted, e.g. in a layout file, it's the order each view appears in the XML.  this is important in e.g. relative layout, because later children draw "on top" of earlier ones.